# IntelliSense-style completion-without-TAB in Xcode

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, intellisense

In Xcode, to complete a suggestion you need to press the TAB key. In Visual Studio, you can just type some punctuation and it will finish the suggestion.

e.g. in VS, typing `f.m();` could expand to `foo.method();`, whereas in Xcode you'd have to type `fTAB.mTAB();`.

Is there any way to emulate VS's behaviour in Xcode?